# undefined method 'image' for nil:class

Tags: ruby, rails-activestorage

Im trying to display all the images from active storage on an index page. Note: The image will display in the show page

Heres what i have on the index page:

```
<% @imagelists.each  do |il| %>
 <%= image_tag(@il.image) &>
<% end %>
```

I can do the following which shows the active storage data

```
<% @imagelists.each  do |il| %>
 <%= @il.image &>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
<% @imagelists.each  do |il| %>
```

You are defining a variable `il` which is available within that `each` block.

However, in your code you are referencing `@il` - an instance variable which doesn't exist. Unlike a normal variable, when you reference an instance variable which isn't defined, you just get `nil`, not a `NoMethodError`.

So, just use `il` instead of `@il` and you'll be fine.